# Do personal likes and comments on feed posts reflect for restricted connections?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments

If I have somebody on a restricted list on Facebook, can they still see my personal likes and comments on my feed?

Comment: I mean to ask, if I restrict somebody, can they still see posts that I like or comments that I make?

Answer (score 1):

Friends in Restricted list can see all your public activity. Such as, your post set to Public, you comments/likes in Public post either post by your friends, Pages and Open Group.

So, don't hit Like or Comment on any Public post and do not tag any restricted friend in any post.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/206571136073851#What-happens-when-I-add-someone-to-the-Restricted-list):

> Putting someone on the [Restricted list](https://www.facebook.com/help/200538509990389?helpref=faq_content) means that you’re still friends, but that you only share your posts with them when you choose [Public](https://www.facebook.com/help/203805466323736?helpref=faq_content) as the audience, or when you tag them in the post.